# Is it possible to send a Websocket connection to a client?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, tornado

folks!

I have the following scenario:

- I'm running a Tornado server with a WebSocketHandler that handles open, on_message and on_close events on a websocket:

  ```
   class WebSocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
       def open(self):
           (...)
       def on_message(self, message):
           (...)
       def on_close(self):
           (...)
  ```
- I have a view where the client opens a new WebSocket and sets the "onmessage" event handler:

  ```
   window.onload = function() {
       ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.51:8080/websocket");    
       ws.onmessage = function(e) {
           console.log(e.data);
       };
   }
  ```
- I would like to change this example a little bit to "reuse" a websocket connection if the user, let's say, opens a new tab in his browser but he has already an opened websocket at the server side.

  I'm intending to do this by sending a user unique id when making the first request to the server and checking the response, before opening a socket.

  **Question is**: If the Tornado server detects that the user already has an opened connection (websocket), is it possible to send to that user(client) a reference to that connection in order to enable the client side code to use it instead of creating a new one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most browsers will open a completely new instance and won't reuse items on other tabs even tho it's the same site. Meaning, the client (the browser) will force a new connection no matter what. This is the fundamental thinking behind all web-trabbic, it's a New->Open->Request->Get->Show request storylyne where you're constantly dealing with new connections :) I understand what you want to achieve, but sadly as mentioned the browser will not take into account that you say "hey, you already have a connection open" and it will simply request a new opening because it's sometimes faster than reusing

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer, @Torxed! Indeed it makes all sense. I'll change the aproach to limit the number of opened sockets per user.
Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, this can be achieved by opening the WebSocket connection from a shared background Web worker.

Opening WebSocket connections from Web workers is not supported (yet) by all browsers. I know it works with dedicated Web workers on Chrome and IE11, and it does not work with Firefox.

I don't know which browsers support opening WebSocket connections from *shared* Web workers.